# "FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly" when using DLL in Blazor App server

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I made a DLL and it's using System.ServiceModel.
When I use the dll in a console App, everything works fine.
But I tried calling it in a Blazor App and now it throws the exception:

> "FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, [...]"

To be sure my issue wasn't from the dll I made, I made a quick console app using the dll.
And to my surprise it works, I can use my dll as is without any issues.

But as soon as I try to use the dll in the Blazor App it throws the "FileNotFoundExeption"

```
[2023-04-26T14:32:16.674Z] Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
File name: 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
[...]
```

Any idea on what could cause it to fail loading the assembly when in the Blazor App?